# How do I reset the ios library in react-native?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I have a new app that was initialised with

```
react-native init demo
```

and is run successfully using `react-native run-ios`.

I installed a few libraries using CocoaPods and now the `react-native run-ios` works but not the xcode build.

I tried deleting the Pods library, checking out all the files back to their original state, and repeating `pod install` but I still get the same error in xcode build :

> Showing Recent Messages :-1: Cycle in dependencies between targets
>   'bridgeTests' and 'Pods-bridgeTests'; building could produce
>   unreliable results. Cycle path: bridgeTests → Pods-bridgeTests →
>   bridgeTests Cycle details: Target build order preserved because
>   “Parallelize Build” is off
>
> → Target 'bridgeTests' has target dependency on Target
>   'Pods-bridgeTests' → Target 'Pods-bridgeTests' has target dependency
>   on Target 'bridge' due to target order in a “Target Dependencies”
>   build phase or the scheme ○ That command depends on command in Target
>   'bridge': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

I would like to somehow rebuild my entire ios library so that an xcode build would work just as the react-native run-ios works.

What's the solution?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: Did you try this? `react-native link`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't solve my problem.. I want to completely recreate those folders.

Answer (score 0):

first delete `ios` & `android` folder, then do

```
react-native <= 0.59.10
react-native-cli <= 1.3.0
```

> react-native eject

```
react-native <= 0.59.10
react-native-cli <= 1.3.0
```

> react-native upgrade --legacy true

[more...](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526#issuecomment-510188117)

Comment: The link you shared is dead.

Comment: Seems like this command doesn't exist - using react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.4.